# Using Ext.crete in Ext.define

Tags: extjs

Is it safe to use an Ext.create call in a Ext.define call ?

Example:

```
Ext.define('app.store.MyStore',{
   extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

   model: Ext.create('Ext.data.Model', {

     idProperty: 'Id',
     fields: [
        { name: 'Id', type: 'number' },
        { name: 'Name', type: 'number' }
     ]
   }), 
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not. In fact with your code the model definition does not even get to the store. Try creating an instance of your store and check what fields the model of the store has:

```
const myStore = Ext.create('app.store.MyStore');
console.log(myStore.getModel().getFields());
```

The result will be an empty array. Now define your model and store like this:

```
Ext.define('app.store.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'Id',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Id',
        type: 'number'
    }, {
        name: 'Name',
        type: 'number'
    }]
});

Ext.define('app.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'app.store.MyModel'
});
```

Try the again to create a store and check for the model fields like above, now you will get an array with two elements, as expected.

Even if it were possible I would not recommend it. Chances are high that you will need this model definition somewhere else in you application.